# ASP.NET Web API 2.2 model binding short-circuits custom model validation

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, model-binding, fluentvalidation, custom-validators

Given I have an Employee model with a nullable GenderID

```
public class Employee
{        
    public int? GenderID { get; set; }     
}
```

And a custom Fluent Validation rule on GenderID using [FluenValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki)

```
RuleFor(x=> x.GenderID).NotNull().WithMessage("Please provide a valid Gender");
```

When I `POST` an Employee to the following endpoint with a `NULL` GenderID

Then the service returns a validation summary as expected.

```
    [HttpPost("Employee/Create")]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody]Employee employee)
    {
        try
        {             
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // return validation summary (code omitted for brevity)
            }

            var result = _respository.CreateEmployee(employee);               

            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

If I change Employee model to have non-nullable GenderID

```
public class Employee
{        
    public int GenderID { get; set; }     
}
```

Then the service returns 400 Bad Request response without processing custom validation. The validation summary is required to bind to UI.

The only reason for having GenderID as nullable is to allow validation summary to be created from custom validators.

How can I apply custom validation without needing to set all my model properties as nullable?

Answer (score 0):

The bad request you receive I think is because of the error converting null GenderId to not nullable int. Is not related to fluent validation. 
Is my opinion if you expect in the request to receive a null GenderId you should keep the property GenderId nullable and let fluent manage the error in its rule. If you think the request will  always contain a not null GenderId then make GenderId not nullable.  A runtime Exception should be thrown if the GenderId, expected to be always not null, is instead null.

Comment: Yes I have already explained the reason but I am trying to find a programming model within WebAPI that allows me to create commands that are more representative to acceptable values. The generated documentation that will accompany my API will be misleading when I mention GenderId can be nullable.